# How to grouping table body element ui

Tags: html-table, nuxt.js, element, element-ui

How can I grouping table body in element ui ?

I've tried to find the solution in the element ui docs, but there is just groping for the header table : https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#grouping-table-head

What I want is grouping in the table body. So, I can do separate colspan in a 1-line row.

What I need is like the below image (red box)

[image: Like this]

I have not idea what to do.

Comment: Which version of Element UI are you using here? What did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I've tried to add a custom div inside el-table-column, but that is not working. And I also tried to manipulate the data to make it loop 3x times for 1 data, so I can manipulate the table body row and add colspan/rowspan on it. But, I think that is not the right way.